# Beginner react, why doesn't my page change?

Tags: reactjs

#### Here is my HTML file:

```html
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

</body>
```

#### This is my JavaScript file:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root')
);
const element = <h1>Hello,world</h1>;
root.render(element);
```

According to this logic, the page should change, the h1 element will appear, but this page has not changed

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's console? You'll probably see a syntax error, because browsers don't interpret JSX by default.

Comment: You might be better off starting with e.g. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/add-react-to-a-website (which doesn't use JSX by default and has a section for moving forward to using it).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have  you imported the necessary libraries (React and ReactDOM) ?

Comment: You  must have styles too

Comment: Even some some browsers which support jsx you have to enable javascript from settings such as Chrome

Comment: I don't think that a question is an answer to a question...